# Symfony: Can a component skip rendering the partial?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

In my view I always want to call a component, but the component sometimes doesn't have to render anything.

Is it possible in this situation to tell symfony to skip rendering the partial?

Rendering an empty partial feels a bit ugly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the component doesn't have to render anything, just `return sfView::NONE;` in the component function.

You could skip using partials and use include_component instead...